# Magento2 Asymmetric transaction rollback error

Tags: magento2, category, error

I am receiving Asymmetric transaction rollback error **when i tried to save Root Category** but when i save other categories it is working fine only for the root category it is showing the error. I have migrated categories from 1.7.0.2 to 2.0.7

Comment: Copy of http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110976/asymmetric-transaction-rollback-error