# Unable to create product programmatically

Tags: products, magento-community, magento-2.1, programmatically, create

I'm trying to create a simple product programmatically in Magento CE 2.1 but I get this error :

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException): Unable to save product
```

The product is created, but the exception is thrown after the creation, it seems that there is a failing rollback.

Here is my snippet :

```
$product = $this->_productFactory->create();
$product->setName('A product');
$product->setSku('a-product');
$product->setPrice(12.3);
$attributeSet = $this->_catalogConfig->getAttributeSetId(4, 'Default');
$product->setAttributeSetId($attributeSet);
$product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
$product->setTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE);
$product->setVisibility(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
$product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
$this->_productRepository->save($product);
```

Comment: could you show the full file, that 'll be more helpful to give the solution

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue. It was the same problem as here : [New Product: "Asymmetric transaction rollback." error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110976/asymmetric-transaction-rollback-error).

I was creating stores programmatically before creating products, causing some index issues. The work-around (as told here : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3720), was to reindex the database after creating a store using the following command :

```
\Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Action\Full::reindexAll()
```

Obviously it is just a work-around and a more stable solution would be appreciated.