# Magento 2 Enterprise, always get error when save customer

Tags: customer, magento-enterprise-2

I have problem with my magento enterprise edition v 2.2, when I create customer account in the frontend and backend I always got the error to be like this :

[image]

when check log file it contain this error

```
[2018-09-20 09:48:09] report.CRITICAL: Exception message: Asymmetric transaction rollback.
Trace: #0 /home/magento22ee/website/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/AbstractResource.php(109): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->rollBack()
#1 /home/magento22ee/website/generated/code/Magento/Customer/Model/ResourceModel/Customer/Interceptor.php(661): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource->rollBack()
#2 /home/magento22ee/website/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Plugin/CustomerRepository/TransactionWrapper.php(48): Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Interceptor->rollBack()
#3 /home/magento22ee/website/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Customer\Model\Plugin\CustomerRepository\TransactionWrapper->aroundSave(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer), NULL)
#4 /home/magento22ee/website/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer), NULL)
#5 /home/magento22ee/website/generated/code/Magento/Customer/Model/ResourceModel/CustomerRepository/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor->___callPlugins('save', Array, Array)
#6 /home/magento22ee/website/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php(726): Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor->save(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer), NULL)
#7 /home/magento22ee/website/generated/code/Magento/Customer/Model/AccountManagement/Interceptor.php(141): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement->createAccountWithPasswordHash(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer), NULL, '')
#8 /home/magento22ee/website/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php(678): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor->createAccountWithPasswordHash(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer), NULL, '')
#9 /home/magento22ee/website/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement->createAccount(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer))
#10 /home/magento22ee/website/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor->___callParent('createAccount', Array)
#11 /home/magento22ee/website/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer))
#12 /home/magento22ee/website/generated/code/Magento/Customer/Model/AccountManagement/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor->___callPlugins('createAccount', Array, Array)
#13 /home/magento22ee/website/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Save.php(237): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor->createAccount(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer))
#14 /home/magento22ee/website/generated/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Save/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save->execute()
#15 /home/magento22ee/website/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save\Interceptor->execute()
#16 /home/magento22ee/website/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(229): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /home/magento22ee/website/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /home/magento22ee/website/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#19 /home/magento22ee/website/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /home/magento22ee/website/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /home/magento22ee/website/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /home/magento22ee/website/generated/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Save/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#23 /home/magento22ee/website/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /home/magento22ee/website/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /home/magento22ee/website/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#26 /home/magento22ee/website/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/magento22ee/website/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#28 /home/magento22ee/website/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /home/magento22ee/website/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#30 /home/magento22ee/website/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#31 {main} [] []
```

I already try to reindex

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

and remove the folder cache

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf var/generation/*
```

then try solution solve this case based this link :

[New Product: "Asymmetric transaction rollback." error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110976/new-product-asymmetric-transaction-rollback-error)

but it still does not work, can anyone help to solve this case ?

Comment: Have you try with disabling custom extension?

Comment: there is only one custom extension, and I just already disabled it.. but the error still appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found how to find the detail error description instead show this message :

```
Exception message: Asymmetric transaction rollback.
```

go to this file in the magento vendor folder and open this Class :

```
<magento_root>\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php
```

then searching this function `rollback()`

and  comment this line code :

```
...
throw new \Exception(AdapterInterface::ERROR_ASYMMETRIC_ROLLBACK_MESSAGE);
...
```

it will force magento to record mysql query error in the system.log and you can trace and debug furthermore based that log. From that mysql error log, I can check my database and find the main problem.

please remember, because this is in the core vendor class, **so don't forget to restore the code after you finished debugging**.

I know this is not the best solutions, but I hope maybe it will help if someone get same issue and he already do `reindex` and clear temporary var folder but still does not work to remove the error.