# catalog search engine is mysql and database engine is mariadb

Tags: catalogsearch, magento-2.1.7

I've recently migrated database from EC2 to RDS.

On EC2 Database engine was MySQL version 15 distribution MariaDB version 10.0.37.

On RDS Database engine is MariaDB version 10.1.14.

And magento catalog search on `Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search` Search engine is MySQL.

The problem is when I try to import products through CSV I get `Asymmetric transaction rollback` and during search I found this [Answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110976/new-product-asymmetric-transaction-rollback-error/159650#159650).

The question is, Should I choose `MySQL` engine for my RDS?

**Update:**

I've performed this [Answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/161224/73375)but in category class instead of product and get that error

```
Recoverable Error: Object of class Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalogRule\Model\Rule could not be converted to string in /part2/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
```

I cannot understand that error, specially because this module is disabled and deleted

Comment: You might want to to `setup:upgrade`, `setup:di:compile` to make sure the module is really gone. If you still find this message afterwards, it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved here https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/issues/299.

I've removed row from `eav_attributes` where `attribute_code = 'virtual_rule'` and it works